# Can I allow DELETE from all origins with groovy-dsl?

Tags: groovy, cors, ratpack

Building a quick and dirty REST API with Ratpack script; can't figure out how to allow DELETE from all origins.

I've tried setting headers within `delete`, and using `all` (as in sample code.)  Sending DELETE with curl, postman, everything always returns 405. Am I missing something simple?

```
@Grapes([
  @Grab('io.ratpack:ratpack-groovy:1.6.1')
])

ratpack {
    handlers {
        all {
            MutableHeaders headers = response.headers
            headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE")
            next()
        }

        post("product") {
            ...
        }

        get("product/:id") {
            ...
        }

        delete("product/:productId") {
            // always returns 405
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see `HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed` response status because your request gets handled by the `get("product/:id")` handler. If you want to use the same path for multiple HTTP methods, you can use `prefix` combined with `byMethod` method to define multiple handlers for the same path.

Consider the following example:

```
import ratpack.http.MutableHeaders

import static ratpack.groovy.Groovy.ratpack

ratpack {
    handlers {
        all {
            MutableHeaders headers = response.headers
            headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE")
            next()
        }

        prefix("product") {
            post {
                render("POST /product")
            }

            prefix(":id") {
                path {
                    byMethod {
                        get {
                            render("GET /product/${allPathTokens.id}")
                        }

                        delete {
                            render("DELETE /product/${allPathTokens.id}")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the example above, you can nest prefixes. We can test it with the following curl requests:

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:5050/product
POST /product%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

$ curl -X GET http://localhost:5050/product/test
GET /product/test%                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

$ curl -X DELETE http://localhost:5050/product/test
DELETE /product/test%
```

If you are interested in more details, I have written a blog post some time ago with a similar example - https://e.printstacktrace.blog/using-the-same-prefix-with-different-http-methods-in-ratpack/

Comment: Thank you sir!  Works great with byMethod.